# Querying historical transaction data from Solana

Tags: transactions, historical-data, query

I am very new to the Solana blockchain being more familiar with Ethereum. I have a requirement to retrieve all transactions for specified addresses from the Solana blockchain and then store them into a database. I have experience of doing this for Ethereum which has a number of 3rd party cloud services which can service this type of request. Can anyone advise what would be the best way to do this for Solana and any particular services which can be used?

Thanks
R

Comment: Can you help me ?
https://solana.stackexchange.com/q/11600/10597

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `getSignaturesForAddress` endpoint https://docs.solana.com/api/http#getsignaturesforaddress followed by `getTransaction` https://docs.solana.com/api/http#gettransaction for each signature returned.

As for services, the public mainnet-beta endpoint api.mainnet-beta.solana.com contains all historical transaction data, but there are other RPC providers that have the data. More information about endpoints at https://docs.solana.com/cluster/rpc-endpoints#endpoints

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look!